# Code-first 1..n mapping error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have these 2 models:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int ProductGroupId {get; set;}
}

public class ProductGroup
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products {get; set;}
}
```

And the mappings:

```
public class ProductMap
{
    this.ToTable("products");

    this.HasKey(t => t.Id).Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("id")
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    this.Property(t => t.Key).HasColumnName("id_product_group")
        .IsRequired();
}

public class ProductGroupMap
{
{
    this.ToTable("product_groups");

    this.HasKey(t => t.Id).Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("id")
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    this.HasOptional(t => t.Products)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete();
}
```

The code compiles but when I start the app, I get the following exception:

> Invalid column "Products_Id"

Is the mapping incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreign key mapping is incorrect.
Replace `HasOptional` code in `ProductGroupMap` with:

```
HasMany(_ => _.Products)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(_ => _.ProductGroupId);
```

This should be read as "ProductGroup has a collection of Products, where product must belong to a ProductGroup, and the relation is controlled by a foreign key property Product.ProductGroupId".

`HasOptional`/`HasRequired` are intended to use for entities, having required/optional *reference* navigation property (e.g., `Product.CountryOfOrigin`), not a *collection* navigation property.

In other words, 1-* association between entities could be configured from both sides: either from principal entity (`ProductGroup` in your case), or from dependent entity (`Product`).

Use `HasMany`, when configuring from the side of principal entity.
Use `HasOptional`/`HasRequired`, when configuring from the side of dependent entity:

- `HasOptional` when the reference to a principal entity is optional;
- `HasRequired` - when reference is required.

Comment: If I change `WithRequired()` to `WithOptional()` would this mean that `ProductGroup` may have 0..n `Products`?

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono: see updated answer. `HasOptional`/`HasRequired` has nothing to do with collections.

Comment: how are `WithRequired()` and `WithOptional()` interpreted?

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono: they establish the association between principal and dependent entities from the point of EF model, but also they says, that dependent entity hasn't reference property to the principal, only a foreign key property (your case). If you'll add `public virtual ProductGroup ProductGroup {get; set;}` in `Product`, you'll use `WithRequired(_ => _.ProductGroup)` overload.